# Encode and decode text into binary and vice versa

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert text into binary and then decode it back to the original text.

When I encode my encoded binary bits are too small. At the decode side I got only the last character of my text string.  My code is given below. Can anyone correct it, if there is any mistake? I want to decode the same text which I encode.

```java
public static String enc(String s) {
///first layer of encoding

        String initializer="11111111";
        int ct=0;
        int a[]=new int[11111111];
        for (int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++){

            a[i]=(int)s.charAt(i);//charAAT retrun value in geven index
            ct++;
        }

        String res ="";
        int bin[] =new int[111];
        int idx=0;
        for(int i1=0; i1 < ct; i1++) {
            int temp =a[i1];
            for(int j = 0; j < ct; j++) bin[j]=0;
            idx = 0;

            while(temp>0) {
                  bin[idx++]=temp%2;
                  temp = temp/2;
            }
            String dig = "";
            String temps;
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                 temps = Integer.toString(bin[j]);

                 dig = dig.concat(temps);

            }
            String rev = "";
            for (int j =dig.length()-1; j>= 0; j--) {
                 char ca = dig.charAt(j);
                 rev = rev.concat(String.valueOf(ca));


            }


            res = rev.concat(rev);

        }
        res = initializer.concat(res);
        return res;
        }
}
```

When encoded, the output for text `hi` is `1111111111010011101001`

The decode part returns only `i` as output:

```java
String invalid = "Invalid Code";

        // create the same initial
        // string as in encode class
        //
        String initailizer = "11111111";
        Boolean flag = true;

        // run a loop of size 8
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            // check if the initial value is same
            if (initailizer.charAt(i) != res.charAt(i)) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        String data = "";
        for (int i = 8; i < res.length(); i++) {
            char temp = res.charAt(i);
            data = data.concat(String.valueOf(temp));
        }
        int asc[][] = new int[11101][8];
        int idx = -1;
        int idx2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            if (i%7==0) {
                idx++;
                idx2 =0;
                char temp = data.charAt(i);
                asc[idx][idx2] = temp-'0';
                idx2++;

            } else
                {
                 char temp = data.charAt(i);
                 asc[idx][idx2] = temp -'0';
                 idx2++;

            }
        }

        int num[] = new int[11111];
        int nidx = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int ct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
            ct = 0;
            temp = 0;
            for (int j=6; j>=0;j--) {

                int temp1 = (int) pow(2, ct);
                temp += (asc[i][j]*temp1);
                ct++;
            }
            num[nidx++] = temp;
        }
        String rv = "";
        char ch;
        for (int i =0; i<nidx; i++) {
            ch = (char) num[i];
            rv = rv.concat(String.valueOf(ch));


        }
        if (data.length()%7 == 0 && flag == true) {
            //return rv;

        }
        return rv;


    }
```

Comment: Note: This is binary representation of utf-16 encoded characters (Java uses utf-16)

Comment: plz explain it i couldn't get

Comment: @ControlAltDel is saying that, since Java represents in-memory characters as encoded in (slightly modified) UTF-16, were you to turn every bit into its binary representation, you would get a lot of leading zeros. e.g. a capital A would be ```000000001000001``` . You probably want 8-bit values, so you might want to use an 8bit char encoding such as Latin1 (if that's possible for the particular text you have). Then you only have 8 bits to turn into binary. Note that ```Integer.toBinaryString```  is essentially broken and will return the minimum number of bits so you'll need to add leading zeros

Comment: Furthering what @g00se wrote (which was a great explanation), there are different text formats (eg ascii, utf-16, utf-8, latin-1,...) for binary encoding of text. The primary purpose of Readers and Writers is to accommodate this more seamlessly (as well as to load Images in different encodings, but these (for images) are different readers/writers)

Comment: Also just FYI some characters are now 2 char (4 byte) characters in Java

Comment: Yes. You could get your string as a byte array and turn that into a string of binary digits

Comment: Great explanations which I think highlight what is missing from the question: what do you mean exactly by "convert text into binary"? What kind of conversion you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks for reply but i can not add lead zero in my code my problm/aim is to convert whole string into binary